# How get fragments from NavController

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I added fragment

```
findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(resId, args)
```

In method onBackPressed

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragment)
val fragments = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments
```

But the parameter `fragments` does not contain my fragment

But

```
val currentDestination = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).currentDestination
val className = (currentDestination as FragmentNavigator.Destination).className
```

`className` is my name class

How to get my fragment and call its method?
Not a single answer on the stack helped me

Comment: Why should you call a method in the fragment in this way?

Comment: And how else should I call the method onBackPressed in my BaseFragment?